# boost::asio socket async_* strand

Tags: sockets, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

How to perform async_* operations on socket through the strand? I've looked at Timer.5 (Boost/Asio examples), but they only show how to invoke user's handler. When I `async_write` to the socket in multithreaded application data may be written corrupted. And a `strand` guarantees that none of those handlers will execute concurrently.

Comment: What are you having problems with specifically?  Performing the async operations not significantly different when using a `strand` vs. _not_ using a `strand`.  Just wrap your handler in the strand.

Comment: This question does not make sense as currently phrased, please edit it and add some clarity.

Comment: It makes a perfect sense to me. I'm having the same problem. Multiple threads are trying to use a single connection read/write requests responses and there are all messed up. What I'm trying to achieve is a squential read request/do whatever needed to process (even another request/response to different service) and then return  response to the original requester.

Answer (score 4):

From **Boost.Asio** docs:

> The io_service::strand class provides the ability to post and dispatch
>   handlers with the guarantee that none of those handlers will execute
>   concurrently.

There's [a good example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3) of `strand` usage in **Boost.Asio** examples.

`strand` guarantees that your handler execution will be synchronized. That means that `strand` is useful if your `io_service` is executed from multiple threads. It's not related to how you schedule your tasks (handlers).

`strand` cannot help you to do multiple socket read or write ops concurrently, because internal read/write execution cannot be done concurrently, so there should be just one active read or write async op.

For `reads` you just call `async_read` to initiate read sequence and call it again from your read handler after consuming received data. The same that you do in single threaded environment.

For `writes` if there're concurrent producers (if multiple threads provides data to be written to socket) you need a concurrent queue (e.g. [boost circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#examples), look for "Bounded Buffer Example"). Your write function takes data from this buffer and async writes it to socket. Your write handler invokes your write function.

Answer (score 3):

> When I `async_write()` to the socket in multithreaded application data
>   may be written corrupted. And Strand guarantee that none of those
>   handlers will execute concurrently.

If multiple threads need to write data on the socket, you will have to ensure ordering of the data. This is explicitly clear in the `async_write()` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html).

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write
>   operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some
>   function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until
>   this operation completes.

I suggest maintain an outgoing queue of messages, which is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7754695/283302) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754695/boost-asio-async-write-how-to-not-interleaving-async-write-calls/7756894#7756894).